# How to set height for a textview if the requirement is Textview should show complete text upto 4 lines after that it should scroll in swift 3?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uitextview

i have a text view at the bottom of the view. I need to show  upto 4 lines of text after that textview text should scroll .
that means if user enter
only one line text -> show single line text
greater than one line(1 - 4) -> textview height should increase and it should show complete text

greater than 4 -> textview should scroll

Comment: follow https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView

Answer (score 0):

i Have integrated 'AUIAutoGrowingTextView' library into my project.
i took heightConstraint outlet of textView as

```
@IBOutlet weak var messageTextViewHieghtConstarint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

i have fixed mixHeight property for textview in viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
  self.messageTextView.maxHeight = 3 * 
       (self.messageTextViewHieghtConstarint.constant)
 }
```